# Scroll Ionic 3 ios

Tags: ios, ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Galera estou com problema nesse scroll, esta criando uma imagem preta no fim da pagina.

Quando arrasto pra cima ele aparece, quando arrasta pra baixo a imagem preta some.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Disponibilize também o código fonte dessa página, assim vamos entender o que está acontecendo!

Comment: Esta acontecendo em todas as paginas.